# org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: /user/rstudio (is not a directory)

Tags: hadoop, rhadoop

I get this error when I try the command in R `> f = hdfs.file('./foo.data', 'r')`.

When I run `# hdfs dfs -ls /user/` I get

```
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   3 rstudio supergroup    3974305 2019-11-09 19:06 /user/rstudio
```

And when I try to create the directory I get

```
# hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/rstudio/
mkdir: `/user/rstudio': Is not a directory
```

Also when I run in R  `> hdfs.file.info('./')` I get

```
perms isDir     block replication   owner      group    size              modtime
1 rw-r--r-- FALSE 134217728           3 rstudio supergroup 3974305 51826-10-07 23:50:34
  path
1   ./
```

Reinforcing that `/user/rstudio` is not a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't.

`-rw-r--r--` would have to start with a `d` in order to be a directory.

You must delete the file using `hdfs dfs -rm`, then use the mkdir command